# how to set default filter month and years?

Tags: html, codeigniter, model

I made filter data based on months and years. well what is the logic when the page loads the filter and that year can be set to the default for the current date and month. the problem is when the page is loaded months and years it has not been set.

.
below I use the manual month and year.

```
function status_data($year,$month){


    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->select("puskesmas.id_puskesmas");
    $this->db->from('puskesmas');
    $this->db->group_by('puskesmas.nama_puskesmas');
    $this->db->join('penyakit', 'puskesmas.id_puskesmas=penyakit.id_puskesmas', 'left');




    $data= $this->db->get()->result();

    foreach ($data as $value) {
        // var_dump($value);die();


        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT *, `puskesmas`.`id_puskesmas` FROM `penyakit` LEFT JOIN puskesmas ON penyakit.id_puskesmas=puskesmas.id_puskesmas WHERE YEAR(waktu_upload) = '$year' AND MONTH(waktu_upload) = '$month' 
            AND penyakit.id_puskesmas=".$value->id_puskesmas);




        $num = $query->num_rows();

         $value->num = $num;
        if($num < 19 ){
            $value->status = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-rounded'> Uncomplete</button>";
        }else{
            $value->status = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-rounded'> Complete </button>";
        }

    }
    //die(print_r($data));
    return $data;
}
```

if i not set this month and years this output will error , how to set default month and years before we submit this post $month and $year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function status_data($year,$month){


    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->select("puskesmas.id_puskesmas");
    $this->db->from('puskesmas');
    $this->db->group_by('puskesmas.nama_puskesmas');
    $this->db->join('penyakit', 'puskesmas.id_puskesmas=penyakit.id_puskesmas', 'left');




    $data= $this->db->get()->result();

    foreach ($data as $value) {
        // var_dump($value);die();


        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT *, `puskesmas`.`id_puskesmas` FROM `penyakit` LEFT JOIN puskesmas ON penyakit.id_puskesmas=puskesmas.id_puskesmas WHERE YEAR(waktu_upload) = '".$year."' AND MONTH(waktu_upload) = '".$month."' 
        AND penyakit.id_puskesmas=".$value->id_puskesmas);




        $num = $query->num_rows();

        $value->num = $num;
        if($num < 19 ){
            $value->status = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-rounded'> Uncomplete</button>";
        }else{
            $value->status = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-rounded'> Complete </button>";
        }
    }

}
//die(print_r($data));    

if (!isset($month) or !isset($year)) {
    $now = new DateTime();
    $month = $now->format("n");
    $year = $now->format("Y");
}

status_data($year, $month);
```

DateTime's format method is documented [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: where i can take this code sir ? on new function on model ? or where ?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include your original code. You want to check whether $month and $year are set before you call the status_data function, that way you avoid getting the error you mentioned in your post.